# How to call the website side widget in odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

- This is my file which was contain template `'website_fb.fb_shared_post'`

  ```
   Qweb.add_template('website_fb_redertemplate.xml');
  ```
- Below code through create a website side `widget` so now if call this `widget` then how to do.
- I refer the `Odoo` documentation but nothing to understandable for me so please help me.

  ```
  var RenderTemplate = Widget.extend({
       template: 'website_fb.fb_shared_post',
       events: {
       // DO some code
       },
      init: function (el) {
       // DO some code
       },
      start: function () {
      // DO some code
       }
    });
  ```

Answer (score 3):

First, when you create widget it will automatically render above XML file that you mention in the first line so below line render another widget template XML file

```
  $(Qweb.render("fb_shared_post", {'res':'Hello'})).prependTo('<TemplateDivID or Class>');
```